# How to get access to another siblings DOM elements in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm wondering how to achieve that.

I'm doing a scrollable one-pager and I made a menu which suppose to navigate to different sections on the page.Of course, what I need to know is what is the distance between section  and top of the page. Menu is one component, the others are siblings to menu. I'd like to get it dynamically, ie. without setting it to fixed heights. I know that one answers could be to find a DOM element by JS, like so:

```
document.getElementById('contactSection')
```

and get a distance of this section from the top of the page. But it seems to be not elegant and probably not recommended way of doing this. Also it is pure JS. 
Could you share how do you access to DOM independent elements?

Thanks!

Comment: *But [...] it is pure JS*. What kind of solution are you looking for?

Comment: you want to show a section when it is clicked from the menu. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I want to get offsetTop of very sections in my app and use it in my vertical scrollable page via menu

Comment: Are you trying to obtain offsetTop in order to scroll to the section on click or for some other purpose. If it is something else, can you mention that so as to provide a solution @Barth

Comment: Yes, that is what I need

Comment: document.getElementById('contactSection').scrollIntoView() should help. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView check the link. There isn't any React way to achieve it